# Structure theorem for modules over PIDs and abelian groups.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modules, principal-ideal-domains

$\textbf{Problem.}$  Let $G$ be the free abelian group $\mathbf{Z}^{5}$.  Show that G has only finitely many subgroups of index 17.

I was looking at an old qualifying exam and this problem was in the "Modules and Rings" section.  I am wondering if there is a module-theoretic solution to this problem that doesn't simply use the fact that any finitely generated group has only finitely many subgroups of a given index.  I currently don't see how this problem is related to the structure of modules over PIDs.

Comment: You can generalize this in a different direction. For any $n>0$ and any finitely generated group $G$, $G$ has only finitely many subgroups of index $n$.

Comment: I know, I mentioned that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Abelian groups = $\mathbb{Z}$-modules, so it is a special case of module over PID.

To answer your second concern in the comments, there is one thing that the proof of the theorem applies to submodules. As an immediate corollary, you obtain that those are also finitely generated, and in fact by at most as many elements as the original. The main idea of the proof is that every submodule has a very special basis. Namely, if $N\leq M$ is a submodule, then it is possible to pick a basis $b_1, \ldots, b_n$ in $M$ and elements $r_1, \ldots, r_n$ in the PID such that $r_1b_1, \ldots, r_nb_b$ is a basis of $N$, and $r_1\mid r_2\mid\cdots\mid r_n$. 
Clearly if the index is 17, then $r_1=\cdots=r_4=1$ and $r_5=17$. If you show that four elements of the original basis must be generated, and $17$ times the fifth also, then you obtain that there are five such subgroups.

Comment: I know, but "I currently don't see how this problem is related to the structure of modules over PIDs"

Comment: Here is one problem I am having.  The structure theorem classifies finitely generated modules up to isomorphism.  But in this problem we want to count all subgroups, not just up to isomorphism.

Comment: I am not even aware of anything interesting that the structure theorem implies about submodules of finitely generated modules.  (There are no exercises in the modules over PIDs section of Dummit and Foote that look anything like these problems.)

Comment: A third thing: the structure theorem applied to free modules over PIDs seems trivial.  It just says $R^{n}=R^{n}$.

Comment: I edit my answer according to your further inquiries.

Comment: Thanks, I see now.  I totally skipped over that theorem when I was looking back in Dummit and Foote.  (In that book, it comes is right before the structure theorem.)